# How do I dynamically launch new containers in backend?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running a docker container which runs a web application deployed on AWS EC2 accessible via its IP address. I want to dynamically create a similar new container every time a user enters the IP address until it reaches its capacity.

I am expecting that new user who visits the IP address will be connected to new container automatically.

Comment: Why would you want to run an individual web app for each user. that sounds like an anti-pattern. Also are you running these containers on AWS ECS using ec2 as the capcity provider or just directly on an EC2 instance?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle - Yes it does, the main reason is R which is a single threaded application because of which if one user is using the app for some tasks then the other user will not be able to use the app since it is still working, hence we are looking for solution such that each new user gets a dedicated container to work on the application. 
PS - We cannot change the code or implement multithreading at code level hence we want to do it at infrastructure level.

Comment: There is no single answer to your question. How do you identify a new user? Do you have some identity management? It sounds like you need a proxy responsible for routing users to underlying containers and provisioning or destroying infrastructure. Again - it's a terrible pattern you are trying to implement. Your web services should be multi-tenant

Comment: For most of our customers we have to only use Single-tenancy in which a single instance of an application serves one customer. For example User 1 enters xyz.com he used default container application hosted on that server, now User 2 enters same domain xyz.com but he gets a second container of same application and so on for N users.

Comment: I am with @olegl this seems like a terrible idea and pattern to implement.

Comment: Yes, I would agree that it is not a good pattern, but due to high security concerns of clients we have to ensure this separation.